Querying for records that may or may not have a specific field in MongoDB
I'm using Prisma with MongoDB and have a Comment model that has a deletedAt field. However, I have existing comments in my database that were created before this field was added to the schema.
I'm trying to query for comments that have parentId set to null and are not deleted, but I need to account for comments that may or may not have the deletedAt field.
My current Prisma query looks like this:
const article = await prisma.article.findUnique({
    where: {
        id: articleId
    },
    include: {
        comments: {
            where: {
                parentId: null,
                deletedAt: null
            },
            orderBy: {
                createdAt: 'desc'
            },
        },
        upvotes: true,
    }
});

This query only returns comments that have the deletedAt field set to null. How can I modify my query to also include comments that don't have the deletedAt field?
Additional Information:

I'm using Prisma with MongoDB.
The deletedAt field was added to the schema after some comments were already created.
I'm aware that MongoDB doesn't have automatic migrations, so I need a way to handle this discrepancy in my query.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or solutions!
I tried using the Prisma query with the OR condition to check for comments where deletedAt is either null or undefined. I expected this query to return all comments that have parentId set to null, regardless of whether they have the deletedAt field or not. However, the query only returned comments that had the deletedAt field set to null.

I would update all documents to match the new schema:
db.article.update({'deletedAt': {$exists : false}}, {$set: {'deletedAt': Null}})

It's a one-off shell command, does not require modification in the code. Consider it is something like a schema migration in SQL ORM's terminology.
You can use this {$exists : false} thingie in the query without updating all documents in the collection, but it may require to update multiple queries now and will be error-prone if the future you will forget about it.

his may take a long time if a large list of documents exists.

yes, this is the price of applying ORM to schemaless database. Besides migrations on RDBS are not immediate either. From my experience it's either using native driver and treat database as a non-trusted source, or using jsonschema and guarantee data structure. There are pros and cons on either side, but these are 2 different mindsets. Combining both is a recipe for a disaster.
